# Java --version gives 1.8.0 even though JAVA_HOME is pointing on C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk-11.0.2\

Tags: java, environment-variables

I got a windows machine and was able to install jdk 11.0.2 and set it up in my enviornment variables , my `JAVA_HOME` environment looks as the following: `C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk-11.0.2\` but when I do java--version I get:

```
java version "1.8.0_192"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_192-b12)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.192-b12, mixed mode)
```

My System path is also point on java 11.0.2

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\windows\system32;C:\windows;C:\windows\System32\Wbem;C:\windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\windows\System32\OpenSSH
\;C:\Program Files\Intel\WiFi\bin\;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Intel\WirelessCommon\;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Program Files\nodejs\;C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker\resources\bin;C:
\ProgramData\DockerDesktop\version-bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk-11.0.2\bin;C:\Dev\Tomcat 8.5\Tomcat 8.5\bin;C:\Users\nxh113\tools\google-cloud-sdk\bin;C:\Users\nxh113\AppData\Lo
cal\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Users\nxh113\AppData\Local\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2020.1\bin;;C:\Users\nxh113\AppData\Roaming\npm;C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk-11.0.2
;C:\Program Files (x86)\apache-maven-3.6.3\bin;C:\Users\nxh113\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\bin;C:\Dev\Tomcat 8.5\Tomcat 8.5\bin;C:\ProgramData\chocoportable\bin;C:\Users\n
xh113\tools\google-cloud-sdk\bin;
```

Any ideas what can it be?

Comment: Add `%JAVA_HOME%\bin` to your PATH as the **first** entry. It searches left to right. And I see the first entry looks like an old Java. It's also 32-bit, so maybe it's one of the other earlier entries. Good luck!

Answer (score 3):

The PATH variable mentioned above contains two entries for Java -

1. C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath
2. C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk-11.0.2\bin

An older version of Java might be present in the first entry (C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath).  That is why, the java command is pointing to the older version.

The problem can be fixed by removing the old entry from the PATH variable.

**Note:**

Change to PATH variable will take effect in the cmd window opened after the change only. The cmd window that was already opened before PATH variable was changed will still use the old PATH only.

Answer (score 0):

another thing you might try is a batch file with:

```
jdk="C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-13.0.2"
javapath="C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath"
mklink %javapath%\java.exe" "%jdk%\bin\java.exe"
mklink %javapath%\javaw.exe" "%jdk%\bin\javaw.exe"
mklink %javapath%\javaws.exe" "%jdk%\bin\javaws.exe"
```

Comment: set jdk=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-12.0.2
set javapath=C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath
mklink "%javapath%\java.exe" "%jdk%\bin\java.exe"
mklink "%javapath%\javaw.exe" "%jdk%\bin\javaw.exe"
mklink "%javapath%\javaws.exe" "%jdk%\bin\javaws.exe"  And finally - Can't create a file because it already exists

Comment: you may have to delete the files/links if they already exist. also, check the permissions.